# where does faile event go in eth contract?

Tags: events

If a function has multi events , the first successed but second faile. Can I get all of them in block?

solidity code like this

```
emit event1
throw
emit event2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`throw` rolls back the whole transaction, so it not only prevents `event2` from being emitted, but also rolls back emission of `event1`.  The final effect will be as if no events were logged at all, so you will see neither `event1` nor `event2` in transaction.